# Which framework is used: PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

I got a code to resolve some errors. But can't figure out which framework or row php is used. Some codes were done in the structure of MVC. Can anybody help me to recognize it?

If anyone help me it will be great help for me. 
I am providing the structure of my code:

```
Main Folder/
       admin/
            controllers/
            htdocs/
            logs/
            views/
            config.php
            log4php.properties
            require.php
       common/
            _common-chk.php
            _common-config.php
            common-chk.php
            common-config.php
            common-func.php
       framework/
            mvc/
       libs/
       manage/
            controllers/
            htdocs/
            logs/
            views/
            config.php
            log4php.properties
            require.php
       models/
            dao/
       public/
            controllers/
            htdocs/
            logs/
            views/
            config.php
            log4php.properties
            require.php
```

Comment: What's the namespace for the framework files? Like in the `framework/mvc`

Comment: There is no namespace in framework/mvc folder's files.

Comment: Check confi.php

Comment: It there's no namespaces, then my guess(!) would be that it's some home made framework. Where did the code come from?

Comment: It comes from Japan. All comments are written in Japani languages.

Comment: There is an unknown terms to me "LOG4PHP". Is it meaning anything?

Comment: log4php is just a logging library: http://logging.apache.org/log4php/

Comment: Many files are smarty files (.tpl). Is it meaning anything?